# How are inflated layouts recycled in onCreate(), etc?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an interface that has two dynamic parts, one of which is more complicated than the other.  I had to spend some time with Bundles and `onSaveInstanceState()`, etc., in order to preserve the state of the first part when the orientation is changed.

Then I turned to do the same with the second, simpler part, and right away noticed that I did not have to do certain things.  The layout for this part is inflated in `onCreate()`, and it contains TextViews and EditTexts whose content can change.  This content is retained, but dynamic changes to the layout are not.

When `onCreate()` is called by restarting the app from the home screen, the changes are not retained.

I have to implement continuity properly via the Bundle anyway, since what is not retained is the state of an object created in `onCreate()` corresponding to the view.  That, and the fact that the behavior is not consistent (restart from homescreen vs. orientation change) make it hard to see this as a "feature", since it implies inflating a "fresh" layout from XML may not always provide a genuinely fresh layout that corresponds exactly to R.layout.whatever.

I'm also guessing this can happen in the context of an Activity's visible lifetime, not just in onCreate(). So what are the rules here?

Comment: do you have `android:configChanges` declared for your activity by chance ?

Comment: @kiruwka No.  I've realized I was mistaken about the dynamic layout changes being retained -- it's just the TextView/EditText content.  Note that in the XML layout, they aren't given any default text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This content is retained, but dynamic changes to the layout are not

Retaining user-mutable content of common widgets, like the text entered into an `EditText`, is automatic, from the built-in implementation of `onSaveInstanceState()`. However, "views... removed from and added to it" (from a previous edition of your question) is definitely not retained by `onSaveInstanceState()`, and if you re-inflate the layout, such changes definitely will be lost.

> When onCreate() is called by restarting the app from the home screen, the changes are not retained.

Well, that will depend upon whether or not the process is still around and whether or not this activity was on the back stack.

> So what are the rules here?

If the user is returning to a specific instance of your activity (configuration change, or starting a fresh process from the recent-tasks list), your saved instance state is applied to the new activity instance that is created.

If the user is starting a fresh process without returning to a specific instance of your activity (e.g., home screen launcher), there is no saved instance state to apply.

Comment: +1 it is nice to know that `super.onSaveInstanceState()` saves text for you. Is it documented somewhere (except source code) ?

Comment: Thanks.  I notice the changes aren't retained if I don't call `super.onSaveInstanceState()`.  This also resolves the potential problem of it happening during the visible lifetime.

Comment: @kiruwka: No, the exact roster of what's saved is not documented anywhere. Generally speaking, it's stuff that users can change (e.g., checked states of `CompoundButton`).

Comment: @CommonsWare I just wonder how you happened to learn this, just by occasionally looking at android code ?